# Is there a Python method to calculate lognormal mean and variance?

Tags: python, matlab, statistics

I am trying to understand if there is a built in python function to calculate the lognormal mean and variance. I require this information only to then feed it into `scipy.stats.lognorm` for a plot overlaid on top of a histogram.

Simply using the `numpy.mean` and `numpy.std` does not seem to be the correct idea, as the lognormal mean and variance are specific and quite different than the numpy methods.    In Matlab they have a handy function called `lognstat` that returns the mean and variance of a lognormal distribution, and I can't seem to track down an analogous method in Python.  It is easy enough to code a work around, but I am wondering if this method exists in a library.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For whatever it's worth, all `lognstat` in matlab does is this:

```
import numpy as np

def lognstat(mu, sigma):
    """Calculate the mean of and variance of the lognormal distribution given
    the mean (`mu`) and standard deviation (`sigma`), of the associated normal 
    distribution."""
    m = np.exp(mu + sigma**2 / 2.0)
    v = np.exp(2 * mu + sigma**2) * (np.exp(sigma**2) - 1)
    return m, v
```

There may be a function for it in `scipy.stats` or `scikits-statsmodels`, but I'm not aware of it offhand.  Either way, it's just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: "`given the mean (mu) and standard deviation (sigma), of the associated normal distribution.`" But what if the original data isn't a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The **python equivalent** of Joe Kington answer would be:

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm

# Mean of normal distribution
mu = 0
# Standard Deviation of normal distribution
sigma = 1

mean, var, *rest = lognorm.stats(sigma, moments='mvsk', scale=np.exp(mu))
```

Where **mean and var would be** the loc and scale **parameters respectively for a lognorm distribution**.

Answer (score 0):

(I do not have rpy install on my notebook at the moment, so I cannot try this out)

You can consider to install [Rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/), which is a python interface to R.

Then you may be able to use this R function http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/stats/html/Lognormal.html